# (Many-valued logic) Disprove that A, not (A and not B) ⊨ (FDE) B by a Routley counter model.

Tags: logic

I have some problems disproving A,¬(A ∧ ¬B) ⊨ B in the logic of first degree entailment(FDE) by a Routley counter model. To do that, I firstly need

$$M_{FDE}⊨ A[w]$$

I also need

$$M_{FDE}⊨ ¬(A ∧ ¬B)[w]$$

That means $$M_{FDE}⊯(A ∧ ¬B)[w^*]$$ (The symbol ⊯ menas ⊨ slash I just do now know how to fix that)

That means either $$M_{FDE}⊯A[w^*]$$ or $$M_{FDE}⊯¬B[w^*]$$

However, if $$M_{FDE}⊯¬B[w^*]$$
then

$$M_{FDE}⊨ B[w]$$ (This cannot happen because we need to disprove the statement).

The other case is $$M_{FDE}⊯A[w^*]$$
That means $$M_{FDE}⊨ ¬A[w]$$. But we have $$M_{FDE}⊨ A[w]$$ in the first place.

My question is **Can that happen?**

Namely, can I have  $$M_{FDE}⊨ ¬A[w]$$ and $$M_{FDE}⊨ A[w]$$ at the same time?

**In other words, can I have $$M_{FDE}={W,*,I}$$ where W={w,w*}, I(A)={w}, I(¬A)={w} as my counter Routley model to disprove the statement?**

Answer (score 1):

> May we have $M \vDash_{FDE} ¬A[w]$ and $M \vDash_{FDE} A[w]$ at the same time?

I think not; the rule for $\lnot$ in a [Routley interpretation](https://books.google.it/books?id=rMXVbmAw3YwC&pg=PA151) is :

> $ν_w(¬A) = 1$ if $ν_{w^∗} (A) = 0$, otherwise it is $0$.

i.e. :

> each world, $w$, comes with a mate, $w^∗$, its *star world*, such that $¬A$ is true at $w$ if $A$ is false, not at $w$, but at $w^∗$. [...] Note that $ν_{w^∗} (¬A) = 1$ iff $ν_{w^{**}} (A) = 0$ iff $ν_w (A) = 0$. In other words, given a pair of worlds, $w$ and $w^∗$, each of $A$ and $¬A$ is true exactly once.

---

I think that the sought counter-model is :

> $w = \{ A \}$ and $w^* = \{ ¬B \}$.

Thus : $M \vDash A[w]$ and applying the rule : $ν_{w^∗} (¬A) = 1$ iff $ν_{w^{**}} (A) = 0$ iff $ν_w (A) = 0$ to the second one, we have : $M \nvDash B[w]$.

But : $M \nvDash A[w^*]$, and thus : $M \nvDash (A ∧ ¬B)[w^*]$, and thus : $M \vDash ¬(A ∧ ¬B)[w]$.

Conclusion : we have :

> $M \vDash A[w]$, $M \vDash ¬(A ∧ ¬B)[w]$ and $M \nvDash B[w]$

that means :

> > $A, ¬(A ∧ ¬B) \nvDash_{FDE} B$.